# un-able to run App showing Failed to install the app

Tags: android, ios, react-native

after Switching my laptop on and running the App using react-native run-android the app is not installing but in the previous day it was working fine (Note: no extra code was added)

I have done some basic research and deleted node_module and done npm install restarted the server cleared watchman cache files but still no hope

```
react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 905 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-locale-detector
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-sensitive-info.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-sensitive-info:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-sensitive-info.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-sensitive-info:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:639:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:657:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/quinoid/Projects/ReactWk/test/DrManar/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (/home/quinoid/Projects/ReactWk/test/DrManar/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
    at then.result (/home/quinoid/Projects/ReactWk/test/DrManar/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-sensitive-info:` is causing the issue.
If you have not added then remove the library or add it again and then link it properly.

Follow the manual instruction to have more control in it.
It's probably linking issue as it couldn't find the library.